# ES6 function definition with object destructuring with defaults

Tags: javascript

So I have this function that has the following JSDoc

```js
/**
 * Initializes a new game, this means creating a new map and centering on the
 * playerbase
 *
 * @param {object} param1
 * @param {number} param1.seed
 * */
```

Currently I have this as the function definition

```js
initNewGame({ seed }) {}
```

But I would like to have a default value for seed, which is `randomInt(0, 100000)`. How can I achieve this.

Comment: when you are defining the function params use `initNewGame({seed: randomInt(0, 100000)})`

Comment: @about14sheep I did try this but it didnt work for some reason

Comment: @about14sheep - the your syntax is incorrect of the key:value pair.

Comment: if you pass something into the function for the param seed it will set the value to that

Comment: `function initNewGame({ seed = randomInt(0, 100000) } = {}) { ... }` If you want to be able to pass it without the parameter completely.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thank you i didnt even catch that!

Comment: the function all is still going to be an issue though.

Comment: Passing a function is another option. Set a default fn ref and call it in `initNewGame`, or pass in a different one.

Comment: @Ivar Your answer did do the trick! Thank you. If you can make it a SO Answer ill mark it answer for other people to find

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
function initNewGame(params, seed = randomInt(0, 100000)) {
   //body of the function
}
```

this can then be called like this:

```
let params = {}
let seed = 4124;
initNewGame(params);
//or 
initNewGame(params, seed);
```

Unfortunately this means that the JSDoc should change accordingly, since seed is not a property of props anymore.

EDIT: another thing you can do is:

```
function initNewGame(params = {anyvalue: "hello", seed: getRandomInt(1000)}) {
  console.log(params.seed)
}

initNewGame();
//or
initNewGame({anyvalue: "hello in call", seed: 1000});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function initNewGame({seed} = {}) {
  seed = seed !== undefined ? seed : randomInt(0, 100000);
  // the rest
}
```